# Mongoose retun nModified : 1 when no data is updated

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Trying to understand why/if mongoose is updating my documents even though no data is changed?

If I save a new document with the query below it will return  this in the console.log(item)

```
{ n: 1,
      nModified: 0,
      upserted: [ { index: 0, _id: 5f3d35c386aeb6c6fb35fa79 } ],
      ok: 1 }
```

Query

```
Product.updateOne(
         {productName: product.productName},
         {$set: newProduct},
         {upsert: true}
      ).then((item) => {
         console.log(item);
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log('Insert  error', e);
    });
```

If i rerun the same query again i get this back. This indicates that the document has been modified but the data is the same, there is no new data that has been inserted.
`{ n: 1, nModified: 1, ok: 1 }`

I've noticed if i remove the stores array, delete the document, insert it again and rerun the query I get `{ n: 1, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }` back in the console.log(item)

I run the same querys, the same amout of time, but when having an array in the object i get this `{ n: 1, nModified: 1, ok: 1 }`  and when not having an array a get this `{ n: 1, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }`

It seems that when having an array the document gets modified regardless if the data is changed.

Example 1
Gives `{ n: 1, nModified: 1, ok: 1 }`

```
const newProduct = {
          ean: product.ean,
          productName: product.productName,
          lowestPrice: product.productPrice,
          mainCategory: categories.mainCategory,
          group: categories.group,
          subCategory: categories.subCategory,
          subSubCategory: subSubCat,
          stores: [{
            name: "foobar",
           }],
        };
```

Example 2
Gives `{ n: 1, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }`

```
 const newProduct = {
          ean: product.ean,
          productName: product.productName,
          lowestPrice: product.productPrice,
          mainCategory: categories.mainCategory,
          group: categories.group,
          subCategory: categories.subCategory,
          subSubCategory: subSubCat,
          
        };
```

Is it me who misunderstands the operation below or whats going on?
What i want to do is:

1.insert if the document don't exists based on productName,

2.if something differs in the document stored in the database and the newProduct, update the document.

3.If nothing differs, do nothing

Product model

```
const ProductSchema = new Schema({
  ean: String,
  productName: String,
  mainCategory: String,
  subCategory: String,
  group: String,
  subSubCategory: String,
  lowestPrice: Number,
  isPopular: Boolean,
  description: String,

  stores: [
    {
      name: String,
      
    },
  ],
});
```

Edit: As its pretty hard to explain I created a small repo that shows the issue.

https://github.com/gameatrix/mongo_array

Comment: "Why is the document modified when I have an array in the object to be inserted and not modified when not having it?" explain second part.

Comment: I've updated the question, hopefully it's a little clearer what im talking about

Comment: You have added two `newProduct` things. Are they related to your doubt which you described in 2 lines just above to that?

Comment: Thats for showing the difference if i insert an array or not. If i have an array i will get ```nModified:1``` and if not i get ```nModified :0```

Comment: What was there in the collection in both the cases?

Comment: It was empty collection in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

**The database still performs the update.**

For example, let's conditionally upsert a value:

```
MongoDB Enterprise ruby-driver-rs:PRIMARY> db.foo.update({a:42},{a:42},{upsert:true})
WriteResult({
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 1,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f3d4ed509fcd40c9f092690")
})
MongoDB Enterprise ruby-driver-rs:PRIMARY> db.foo.update({a:42},{a:42},{upsert:true})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
```

The first write was an insert, the second write was an update. The second write did not change any data but the database performed a write.

You can verify there was a write by using a change stream in another shell instance:

```
MongoDB Enterprise ruby-driver-rs:PRIMARY> db.foo.watch()
{ "_id" : { "_data" : "825F3D4ED5000000012B022C0100296E5A1004FAC29486D5A3459A8726349007F2E43E46645F696400645F3D4ED509FCD40C9F0926900004" }, "operationType" : "insert", "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1597853397, 1), "fullDocument" : { "_id" : ObjectId("5f3d4ed509fcd40c9f092690"), "a" : 42 }, "ns" : { "db" : "test", "coll" : "foo" }, "documentKey" : { "_id" : ObjectId("5f3d4ed509fcd40c9f092690") } }
{ "_id" : { "_data" : "825F3D4ED6000000012B022C0100296E5A1004FAC29486D5A3459A8726349007F2E43E46645F696400645F3D4ED509FCD40C9F0926900004" }, "operationType" : "replace", "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1597853398, 1), "fullDocument" : { "_id" : ObjectId("5f3d4ed509fcd40c9f092690"), "a" : 42 }, "ns" : { "db" : "test", "coll" : "foo" }, "documentKey" : { "_id" : ObjectId("5f3d4ed509fcd40c9f092690") } }
```

By definition an upsert either modifies documents that match the condition or inserts new documents. You are always going to have a write when upserting.

> 2.**if something differs in the document stored in the database and the newProduct**, update the document.

The bolded part is not how MongoDB (and most databases, as far as I know) work. Whether a write is performed does not depend on whether the data being written is the same as what is already in the database.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I dont understand why i get nModified:1 back when running an update with an array and nModified:0 without the array?

Comment: I only see one update on top of the post. If you tested other updates, add them to the question as mongo shell commands.

Comment: Its the same update query but two different objects that i insert. Example 1 has an array (stores) and example 2 dont. When inserting example 1 i get nModified:1 back. When inserting example 2 i get nModified:0 back. (ive added the exmaple 1 & 2 text to the post)

Comment: I see some mongoose declarations but no code runnable in mongo shell.

Comment: Dont really know how to use mongo shell, sorry. I've created a small project on github with code that runs and shows the issue. https://github.com/gameatrix/mongo_array

Comment: You can get the equivalent diagnostic information out of a driver but the shell is generally easier to use. Regardless of how you obtain them, the commands sent to the server and responses you received are required.